# Is function trailing return type evaluated when requires clause fails

Tags: c++, c++20, sfinae, c++-concepts

Simple code as below or as on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/n9n7r3Tjc) doesn't compile with clang but compiles fine with gcc and Visual Studio.

The trailing return type `decltype(foo(t))` of `baz(T t)` is not evaluated when SFINAE fails with clang, gcc and Visual Studio.

However, the trailing return type `decltype(foo(t))` of `bar(T t)` is still evaluated when requires clause fails with clang. The trailing return type is not evaluated when requires clause fails with gcc and Visual Studio. Which compiler is correct on this?

Thank you.

```
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
auto foo(T) {
    static_assert(std::is_integral<T>::value); // clang error: static_assert failed due to requirement 'std::is_integral<double>::value'
    return 5;
}
 
template<typename T> requires std::is_integral<T>::value
auto bar(T t) -> decltype(foo(t)) {
    return foo(t);
}

template<typename T> requires (!std::is_integral<T>::value)
auto bar(T) {
    return 1.5;
}

template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<T>::value>* = nullptr>
auto baz(T t) -> decltype(foo(t)) {
    return foo(t);
}

template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<!std::is_integral<T>::value>* = nullptr>
auto baz(T) {
    return 1.5;
}

int main()
{
    bar(5.); // fails with clang, works with gcc and VS
    baz(5.); // works with clang, gcc and VS
}
```

Comment: FWIW, trailing return types don't appear to have anything to do with this: https://godbolt.org/z/jW5bE3qsG

Comment: @Frank Yes, decltype triggers the error. It compiles fine with just auto.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is [CWG 2369](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/2369.html), which clang does not appear to implement yet.

The example in that issue (which can now be found in [[temp.deduct.general]/5](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.general#5)) doesn't compile on clang, but does on gcc.

```cpp
template <class T> struct Z {
  typedef typename T::x xx;
};
template <class T> concept C = requires { typename T::A; };
template <C T> typename Z<T>::xx f(void *, T); // #1
template <class T> void f(int, T);             // #2

struct A {} a;

struct ZZ {
  template <class T, class = typename Z<T>::xx> operator T *();
  operator int();
};

int main() {
  ZZ zz;
  f(1, a);   // OK, deduction fails for #1 because there is no conversion from int to void*
  f(zz, 42); // OK, deduction fails for #1 because C<int> is not satisfied
}
```